# TCP over RS-232 with Windows 3.1 and Internet Explorer 5 dialer

Tags: windows-3.x, modem, internet

I am restoring a Windows 3.1 computer that has Internet Explorer 5 installed. I would like to connect it to the internet using a Linux-based laptop as an intermediary.

The physical connection is working fine and is connected as follows:

```
386 -> RS-232 to USB adapter (COM2) -> Linux Laptop
```

I have read that [pppd allows init and connect scripts](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pppd) for adding special logic to PPP connections, but **I can not find any resources directly related to "tricking" Windows 3.1 into thinking that the laptop on the other side of the null modem cable is an ISP. Is this possible via special configuration?**

Some other clarifications:

- I am using the IE 5 dialer
- IE 5 comes with full TCP/IP support when you use the included dialer

**UPDATE:** I got it to work, but not with the default IE 5 dialer. I ultimately had to use Trumpet Winsock to get things running, as was suggested by some users in the comments of this question.

Comment: I don't think it any trickery is needed. The Linux system just has to route traffic, and probably provide a NAT function (since you likely only have one IP address from your ISP).

Comment: You may want to also consider an ISA Ethernet card (E-Bay has some 3Com Etherlink III cards for less than C$20.00) and TCP/IP stack: 10Mbps isn't exactly fast, but it's going to be much faster than a (possibly 9600bps) serial link.

Comment: @ErikF There are a lot of different Ethernet standards that can not necessarily be mixed. Example: 100MBit/s Broad-R-Reach cannot simply be connected to a 100MBit/s Base-T network. I doubt that a 10MBit/s card can be connected to a "modern" Ethernet network.

Comment: @MartinRosenau 10BASE-T is not considered obsolete and is still supported on modern switches.  BroadR-Reach wasn't ratified until a few years ago, so I'd put the odds of a consumer getting hold of hardware that supports it at vanishingly small and the odds of there being an ISA card supporting it at nil.

Comment: In addition to [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol), you might want to research its predecessor, [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol).  These were the two most common methods for connecting back in that era.  [Trumpet WinSock](http://www.trumpet.com.au/) was the most common stack during my Windows 3.1 days.

Comment: If you emulate an ISP at the other end of the serial cable, how would that help? What the dialer is expecting to be there is a modem, no? Your request is confusing.

Comment: Just FYI, the minimum requirement for Internet Explorer 5 for Windows 3.1 noted in its README is a 486/25 with 12MB of RAM, which isn't exactly a typical Windows 3.1 era machine; on a less powerful machine you may want to try an earlier IE release.

Comment: @rakslice I finally got the machine working (had to use Trumpet Winsock instead of dialer), so those requirements may have been on the side of caution. I was able to load a few light pages that did not have a ton of HTML.

Comment: If you still want to do it with PPP, you'll need an "ISP side" variant of it. I tried this once (though with `pppd` at the other end, not with a Win 3.1 PPP), and can try to dig up my notes, if you are interested.

Comment: @Rick Congratulations! Did you end up posting any blog page/tutorial on what you did? I would be interested in replicating it with my old laptop! :)

Comment: @user3141592 Yes the results were posted here: https://rickcarlino.com/2019/386-restoration-progress-part-ii.html

Answer (score 1):

> ... to "tricking" **Windows 3.1** into thinking that the laptop on the other side of the null modem cable is **an** ISP.

What dial-up software do you have?

As far as I know, Windows 3.1 came without any TCP/IP support itself, but you had to install the TCP/IP support ("winsock.dll") from another source.

I remember that my provider published CD-ROMs that contained the dial-up software including TCP/IP support.

If you have such kind of dial-up software, I doubt that it will work with any other provider. Maybe such a dial-up software will even drop the connection if it does not receive "special" IP packets **after** the PPP connection has been established.

If you have some dial-up software that works with any provider but requires a dial-up modem, you could write some C/Perl/Python/Java/... program that emulates a modem dial-up phase:

Incoming bytes from the standard input are ignored until you see "A"+"T". You remember the next byte; if it is not CR, you wait until you receive CR.

If the byte following the "A"+"T" was a "D", you write "CONNECT"+CR+LF to the standard output and exit the program.

Otherwise you write "OK"+CR+LF and continue waiting for "A"+"T"... (the entire program is an endless loop which only ends if "A"+"T"+"D" is seen).

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [Windows 3.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x) confirms that 3.1 didn't support TCP/IP without the use of a 3rd-party [Winsock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock) package until a 1994 add-on (Wolverine) for [Windows for Workgroups 3.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x#Windows_for_Workgroups_3.11) (and also notes that that implementation didn't support dial-up).

Comment: [Trumpet winsock](http://www.trumpet.com.au) was the one everybody used IIRC.

Comment: I am using the dialer that comes with internet explorer 5. That includes a full tcp stack also.

Answer (score 1):

When I did this back in the day, I had a "normal" dial up Unix shell session.

What I was able to do was call up normally, and get to a shell prompt.

At that point, I'd execute pppd on the server, from the command line.

Then, on my Unix system, I fired up client software telling it use the serial port I was using for the modem.

At that point I had connectivity.

pppd works on both ends, it's both the client and the server.

You simply need to have pppd listening on the serial line that you have from the incoming side of the process, and then have your client open the serial port on the client. You don't need dial scripts, since you're not dialing -- you have no modem.

At this point, it may Just Work. I'm just not familiar enough with your client package to give hints on how to pull it off.

While there's 32,768 options for pppd, when I used it was very simple.

If you were running a linux box on both ends, and tried to share on /dev/tty1 on each, it's close to as simple as typing "pppd tty1 19200" on both machines.

You just need to figure out how to get your "dial" software to work. If it's assuming there's always a modem on the other side, you'll have trouble (though you might be able to create a "connect script" on the server side to make it LOOK like a modem (i.e. accept modem commands, and return appropriate replies).